# Errors when EditText left blank

Tags: java, android

Can anyone take a look at the below code and point out the obvious on what's wrong? The program gives an error when `editText` is left blank and only does the calculation once all the information is present. Currently the program crashes when there is text missing, why is this?

```
EditText editText1, editText2;
double numA, numB, numC;
TextView answer;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.calc);

    editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    editText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
}

public void btnClick(View v)
{
    if(editText1.getText().length()==0)
    {
        editText1.setError("please input text"); 
    }{
        if  (editText2.getText().length()==0)
            {
                editText2.setError("please input text");
            }

    numA = new Double(editText1.getText().toString());
    numB = new Double(editText2.getText().toString());

    numC=(numA + numB); answer.setText(Double.toString(numC));
    }
}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to parse `""` into a number (a double, specifically). You are checking for empty values, but you're still attempting to parse it even if you set the error. You need to place the `new Double()` statements in a try-catch block, and catch the exceptions that happen when trying to parse an invalid input. This way, it's safe even if the user inputs a random string of text that is also not parseable as a double.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this:

```
if(TextUtils.isEmpty(editText1.getText()))
{
    editText1.setError("please input text"); 
}
if(TextUtils.isEmpty(editText2.getText()))
{
    editText2.setError("please input text"); 
}
```

What `TextUtils.isEmpty(str)` does is return `str == null || str.length() == 0`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

Just Replace your statement with these..and it will work.

```
if ((editText1.getText().toString()).equals(null))


if ((editText2.getText().toString()).equals(null))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Do

```
if(editText1.getText().toString().equals(null){//your code here}
if(editText2.getText().toString().equals(null){//your code here}
```